# Deleting Extended Properties of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database where I put comments in the `Description` property of many columns in my tables to describe the columns.  The Description property apparently is implemented as an `Extended Property` named `MS_Description`.

Now I need to copy the database to SQL Azure, that does not permit `Extended Properties`.  What is the Transact SQL commands available to search every column for the Extended Property MS_Description and delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here you have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177541%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) a detailed explanation on how to list extended properties on SQL Server 2008R2.
Then at the end of that page you have several references, one of them is to the [`sp_dropextendedproperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178595%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Make use of it at will.

One blog with [useful information](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/fun-with-extended-properties-in-sql-server-2008/) and detailed samples.

Here you have a code sample to show all extended properties for columns in a table:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT major_id, minor_id, t.name AS [Table Name],
       c.name AS [Column Name],
       value AS [Extended Property]
  FROM sys.extended_properties AS ep
 INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON ep.major_id = t.object_id 
 INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id
       AND ep.minor_id = c.column_id
 WHERE class = 1;
GO
```

Even [more samples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to do a wildcard delete on all MS_Description in any column in any table?  sp_dropextendedproperty seems to take only one at a time.

Comment: Hi there, here is the script: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/747cb7c2-b176-4f75-9d92-c5a9360b4ed3/drop-extended-property-msdescription-of-all-tables-and-all-columns?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

These sentences were useful to me:

```
-- find the property of a specific column
    SELECT * FROM SYS.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES 
        WHERE [major_id] = OBJECT_ID('My_Table') 
        AND [name] = N'MS_Description' 
        AND [minor_id] = (SELECT [column_id], * FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
         WHERE [name] = 'My_Column' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('My_Table') )

-- find a random property in all columns in a table (useful when a column was deleted but the property was left behind)
    SELECT * FROM SYS.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES 
        WHERE [major_id] = OBJECT_ID('My_Table') 
        AND [name] = N'MS_Description' 
        AND CAST([value] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%"Nombre": "My_Column"%'





 -- drop extended properties from an existing column
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM SYS.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES 
            WHERE [major_id] = OBJECT_ID('My_Table') 
            AND [name] = N'MS_Description' 
            AND [minor_id] = (SELECT [column_id], * FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
            WHERE [name] = 'My_Column' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('My_Table')  )
    )
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_dropextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
        @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
        @level0name = N'dbo',
        @level1type = N'TABLE',
        @level1name = N'My_Table',
        @level2type = N'COLUMN',
        @level2name = N'My_Column';
    END
```